# How to add a StateStore using StateStoreBuilder in a Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Streams application

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

The native Kafka API allows us to [create and add a state store using the StreamsBuilder](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/5.2.1-post/src/test/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/EventDeduplicationLambdaIntegrationTest.java#L210):

```
    final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
    ...
    final StoreBuilder<WindowStore<String, Long>> dedupStoreBuilder = Stores.windowStoreBuilder(
            Stores.persistentWindowStore(storeName,
                                         retentionPeriod,
                                         windowSize,
                                         false
            ),
            Serdes.String(),
            Serdes.Long());

    builder.addStateStore(dedupStoreBuilder);
```

I would like to do the same using Spring Cloud Streams but can't figure out the way to access the `StreamsBuilder` to add the store.

I've tried to retrieve the `StreamsBuilderFactoryBean` as stated in the  [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle), hoping the I could get the `StreamsBuilder` object from it, but the bean doesn't seem to be available:

```
@EnableBinding(KafkaStreamsProcessor::class)
class FraudKafkaStreamsConfiguration(private val context: ApplicationContext) {

    @StreamListener
    @SendTo("output")
    fun process(@Input("input") input: KStream<String, TransferEmitted>): KStream<String, TransferEmitted> {

        val streamsBuilderFactoryBean = context.getBean("&stream-builder-process", StreamsBuilderFactoryBean::class.java)
        ...
        return xxx

    }

}
```

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named 'stream-builder-process' available

In any case I'm not even sure that's the right way to do it. So, how can we programatically create a `StateStore`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't see the documented procedure because of my Scs version (Fishtown SR3), but the good news is that it's possible to create the State Store declaratively since Germantown:

```
const val DEDUP_STORE = "dedup-store"

@EnableBinding(KafkaStreamsProcessor::class)
class FraudKafkaStreamsConfiguration {

    @KafkaStreamsStateStore(name = DEDUP_STORE, type = KafkaStreamsStateStoreProperties.StoreType.KEYVALUE)
    @StreamListener
    @SendTo("output")
    fun process(@Input("input") input: KStream<String, TransferEmitted>): KStream<String, TransferEmitted> {
        return input.transform(TransformerSupplier { DeduplicationTransformer() }, DEDUP_STORE)

    }

}
```

Comment: This should be available in Fishtown too (2.1.3 version of the binder). https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/2.1.3.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_state_store

Comment: My bad, you're right! I was checking the spring cloud stream documentation https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/2.1.3.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-stream.html, not the binder where it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56630142/how-to-add-a-statestore-using-statestorebuilder-in-a-spring-cloud-stream-kafka-s/56631031?noredirect=1#comment99838888_56631031